# How do I compose three overlapping videos w/audio in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have three videos: let's call them `intro`, `recording` and `outro`. My ultimate goal is to stitch them together like so:

[image]

Both `intro` and `outro` have alpha (prores 4444) and a "wipe" to transition, so when `overlay`ing, they must be on top of the recording. The recording is h264, and ultimately I'm encoding out for youtube with [these recommended settings](https://gist.github.com/mikoim/27e4e0dc64e384adbcb91ff10a2d3678).

I've figured out how to make the thing work correctly for `intro` + `recording`:

```sh
$ ffmpeg \
  -i intro.mov \
  -i recording.mp4 \
  -filter_complex \
  "[1:v]tpad=start_duration=10:start_mode=add:color=black[rv]; \
   [1:a]adelay=delays=10s:all=1[ra]; \
   [rv][0:v]overlay[v];[0:a][ra]amix[a]" \
  -map "[a]" -map "[v]" \
  -movflags faststart -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -bf 2 -g 30 -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
  out.mp4 -y
```

However I can't use the `tpad` trick for the outro because it would render black frames over everything.

I've tried various iterations with `setpts`/`asetpts` as well as passing `-itsoffset` for the input, but haven't come up with a solution that works correctly for both video and audio. This tries to start the outro at 16 seconds into the recording (10s start + 16s of recording is how I got to `setpts=PTS+26/TB`).  del, but doesn't work correctly, I get both intro and outro audio from the first frame, and the recording audio cuts out when the outro overlay begins:

```sh
$ ffmpeg \
  -i intro.mov \
  -i recording.mp4 \
  -i outro.mov \
  -filter_complex \
  "[1:v]tpad=start_duration=10:start_mode=add:color=black[rv]; \
   [1:a]adelay=delays=10s:all=1[ra]; \
   [2:v]setpts=PTS+26/TB[outv]; \
   [2:a]asetpts=PTS+26/TB[outa]; \
   [rv][0:v]overlay[v4]; \
   [0:a][ra]amix[a4]; \
   [v4][outv]overlay[v]; \
   [a4][outa]amix[a]" \
  -map "[a]" -map "[v]" \
  -movflags faststart -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -bf 2 -g 30 -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
  out.mp4 -y
```

I think the right solution lies in the direction of using `setpts` correctly but I haven't been able to wrap my brain fully around it. Or, maybe I'm making life complicated and there's an easier approach?

In the nice-to-have realm, I'd love to be able to specify the start of the `outro` relative to the end of the recording. I will be doing this to a bunch of recordings of varying lengths. It would be nice to have one command to invoke on everything rather than figuring out a specific timestamp for each one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `adelay` for all audio adjustments. Perform all mixing in a single `amix`.
Set the outro overlay to start only at the correct timestamps.

Use

```
$ ffmpeg \
  -i intro.mov \
  -i recording.mp4 \
  -i outro.mov \
  -filter_complex \
  "[1:v]tpad=start_duration=10:start_mode=add:color=black[mainv]; \
   [1:a]adelay=delays=10s:all=1[maina]; \
   [2:v]setpts=PTS+26/TB[outv]; \
   [2:a]adelay=delays=26s:all=1[outa]; \
   [mainv][0:v]overlay=eof_action=pass[previd]; \
   [previd][outv]overlay=enable='gte(t,26)'[v]; \
   [maina][0:a][outa]amix=inputs=3[a]; \
  -map "[v]" -map "[a]" \
  -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -bf 2 -g 30 -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
  -movflags +faststart \
  out.mp4 -y
```